# Increment column value by one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to update a column (`int`) and it is not incrementing by 1 like I want it to, but it's incrementing by every 8 rows. So it is doing this:

**Table1**:

```
ID  FIELD_NUMBER
----------------
1    3507572
2    3507572
3    3507572
4    3507572
5    3507572
6    3507572
7    3507572
8    3507572
9    3507573
10   3507573
11   3507573
12   3507573
13   3507573
14   3507573
15   3507573
16   3507573
```

It should increment by 1 3507572, 3507573, etc

Code:

```
DECLARE @id INT 
SET @id = 3507571 

UPDATE table1
SET @id = FIELD_NUMBER = @id + 1 
GO
```

Not sure why. I am using SQL Server 2012. Thoughts?

Comment: This is not a guaranteed approach. Probably you are getting a parallel plan with DOP of 8.

Comment: What do you mean by DOP?

Comment: Degree of parallelism. You should use row_number instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better approach is to use an updatable CTE:

```
DECLARE @id INT;
SET @id = 3507571;

with toupdate as (
      select t1.*, row_number() over (order by field_number) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     )
update toupdate
    set field_number = @id + seqnum;
```

Comment: Should declare '@id' like normal before the script?

Comment: It should be `order by id` I imagine.